# CoreDataBooks Example Alterations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am basing my CoreData usage of that of in Apple's CoreDataBooks Example and there are some alterations I would like to make but need a few tips.

If you don't mind downloading and running it quickly, the example will make things much clearer in understanding my point.

You have your tableview of books, then a view to view that book, then a third view if you want to edit one of the attributes of that selected book.

I want to remove that third view, so when you select the edit button each cell simply changes to an appropriate thing, such as  book name change to a textfield so that can be edited and saved, when tapping on the date cell the date picker pops up right there.

I think its important to simplify the experience as much as possible and removing as much as possible for the user would be better?

Let me know what you think.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is definitely not a good idea. The whole point of the second view for editing is that it simplifies the procedure. If you remove that view, you will have to hide everything on the screen, then show the textfield. And since Core Data Books implements the detail view using a UITableViewController, you cannot "hide" the table simply. Instead, you would have to redo the detail view controller to be a normal view controller with a table view inside of it that can be hidden when desired. This seems like a lot of work to simplify something that is already effective and easy. Why try to reinvent the wheel here?

Comment: I just spent the better part of a month working with this example. In that time, I've discovered that this app is extremely efficient, and very well written.